# PdfParser or Pdf2Text both Class not able to return the currect converted data

Tags: php, pdf

I have used pdf2text converter to convert pdf to text. It works fine for some  pdf only. For some pdf it is returning a non readable data or some other format.

After that I have used PdfParser Class it also reflecting the same issue with the same pdf. Can anyone please guide to solve this problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/smalot/6183152  (This is for PdfParser Class)

Comment: https://www.interactivetools.com/forum/forum-posts.php?postNum=2198581 (this is for Pdf2Text Class)

Comment: could you provide example of non-readable pdf?

Comment: 271C1201091A151020010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010D0E21290E252222 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<51501181E01141A2C011210141610151A1F1101151A0112131415181A14010F131F121014131415010619191A1C141501071C1234131F01360F06073B01181401090B2701 08131F151833181910151325010F2013101E13011E1C3412181501111A1C1F010F0607012601183301141A1501161A1413011518202001141A2C2601151A01131410342013011C1E01 151A01181E1E1C1301090B270119131F1518331819101513250105140119101E132601111A1C011

Comment: like this i am getting the response. Combination of binary and hexadicimals

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question.